# How to write a function that takes a closure of a view and returns a view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm wanting to write utilities that work with views to do things like conditionally show views and do things like `intersperse` where a view is repeated and some kind of separator is inserted between each iteration.  I can't figure out how to define the function type signature.  This is what I got so far:

```swift
    func ifNotLastCategory(_ cat: String, content: () -> AnyView) -> AnyView {
        if (cat != movie.categories.last) { return content() }
    }


    ...
    
    ifNotLastCategory(category) { Text("Hello World") }
```

When I try to do something like that I get a compiler error about `Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to closure result type 'AnyView'`.  However it won't let me define `content` as returning `some View`.

How can I make this function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic function and cast the result to `AnyView`:

```
func ifNotLastCategory<V: View>(_ cat: String, content: () -> V) -> AnyView {
    if cat != movie.categories.last { return AnyView(content()) }
    return AnyView(EmptyView())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try not to use `AnyView` unless you really have a good reason for it. In most cases you can use other solutions which are more *efficient* and *cleaner*.

In your case I suggest using a `@ViewBuilder` and returning *some View*:

```
@ViewBuilder
func ifNotLastCategory<V: View>(_ cat: String, content: () -> V) -> some View {
    if cat != movie.categories.last {
        content()
    }
}
```